# Memory usage increasing, can't identify what is causing the issue

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, metal

I am using Swift to make a game, and when the game is opened, the usage will reach 90 MB instantly then it will increase at roughly 0.1 MB every 20 seconds.

Using instruments, I am able to observe that the persistent Bytes of two categories are increasing: `CAMetalDrawable` and `_NSArrayM`.

[image: Instrument]

As you can see by the amount of persistent#, they are not being released.

Can anyone identify these categories?

What they could be so I could try and remove them in my code to retest to see if they were the issue.

A bit more info, my app uses a SKScene which is not the problem as I have removed it and tested it again and the issue is still present.

I am using:

- 5 iCarousels.
- About 100 images that are loaded with UI(imageContentsOfFile) and thus are not cached.
- IAPs
- NSUserDefaults
- GameCenter for Leaderboards
- And nothing special after that.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Edit #1: I've removed all iCarousels and tested. Issue still present.

Edit #2: From the following images, the two categories seem to be causing each other. I have included a look into each category.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Here is a frame capture with the Metal validation layer enabled. This is idle after open and the memory usage is increasing still at the rate of 0.1 MB every 20 seconds.

[image: FPS]

EDIT #3

I can confirm that the exponential leak occurs upon pressing cancel on this screen. Which appears immediately on launch of the app.

[image: leak]

Comment: Are you running with GPU frame capture and the Metal validation layer enabled?

Comment: @warrenm Could you have a look at my screen shot?

Comment: This might be a memory leak in the frameworks. It's probably worth [filing a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com), especially if you can attach a project that reliably reproduces the unbounded memory usage.

Comment: I found this temporary fix and posted it here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64295